# Code Igniter update query result + ajax success

Tags: codeigniter

I am using jquery ajax to update a field. Now I am able to update using update query to database.

My update function has a return statement. How do I updated the div using ajax success function.

Should I pass it to controller then I should pass to view ?

Answer (score 0):

how about having a function ajaxupdate() in your controller which returns the new contents of a div to update and replace the content of that div with the new content. Then, in your view, all you need is something along those lines

```
<div id='AjaxDiv'>Contents of this div is replaced</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          UpdateAjaxDiv();
       });

        function UpdateAjaxDiv(){
           $('#AjaxDiv').load('<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/ajaxupdate');
            setTimeout(UpdateAjaxDiv, 5000);
        }
    </script>
```